# C# WebClient StreamReader string replace not working

Tags: c#, webclient, streamreader

I want to read the response from the URI and modify it by replacing all S's to X's and to return that string back to client. 
Below is my code, but **replace** is not working.
I downloaded the "response" string to check and there are lots of S characters.
Any idea why this is not working or how can I manipulate this ?

```
try
        {
            // open and read from the supplied URI
            stream = webClient.OpenRead(uri);
            reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            response = reader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Replace('S', 'X');
            webClient.DownloadFile(uri, "C://Users//MyPC//Desktop//a.txt");

        }
```

Thanks..

Comment: `response.Replace()` returns a string. You're not assigning it to anything.

Answer (score 1):

you can use webClient.DownloadString(uri)

like this:

```js
string str = webClient.DownloadString(uri).Replace('S', 'X');
            File.WriteAllText(@"C://Users//MyPC//Desktop//a.txt", str);
```

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks.
By the way my mistake is I didn't assign response.Replace('S', 'X') to a string. Assigning and returning that new string solves that too ;)